# How to avoid loading referenced documents when creating a new document?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

I have a `Playlist` document which references many `Song` documents, which in turn reference others documents:

```php
/** @Document(collection="playlists") */
class Playlist
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Song", simple=true)
     */
    protected $songs;
}

/** @Document(collection="songs") */
class Song
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Foo", simple=true)
     */
    protected $foo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Bar", simple=true)
     */
    protected $bar;
}
```

Another document `Like` references one `Playlist`:

```php
/** @Document(collection="likes") */
class Like
{
    /**
     * @var Playlist
     *
     * @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Playlist", simple=true)
     */
    protected $playlist;
}
```

Each time I persist (insert) a new `Like` document, some of the references (deep or not) are loaded (a lot of associated queries are executed) ; which is, in that specific case, useless.

How can I avoid this "greedy" behavior (model refactor, configuration, caching etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

use manual referencing:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#manual-references

In short store a `"List"` id in the `Articles` it's associated with.

Then when you change the `"List"` you do not need to load all the associated articles.

You can get all Articles for a given "list" still with:

`db.articles.find({"listId" : "foo"})`

I think the purpose of the `"List"` collection will change - unsure without seeing your schema. This the reason for quotes around `"List"`.